# Silent token retrieval in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Is there a way for a native/WPF application to get Identity Server 4 to issue a token without the need for a user interface in the way that Microsoft's MSAL library allows you to - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication.

The MSAL library only works where you have a Windows user that is backed up in the Azure AD tenant specified by the authority property.

Using the .NET HttpClient class, I was hoping that if I set the UseDefaultCredentials in the HttpClientHandler and setup Identity Server so it uses Windows Authentication as its "provider" that this would be possible.

However when trying it I get a 401 Unauthorized when it tries to authenticate the user at [this point](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/5db239b61f105da240f69b5cc1fa77fa8c0fa541/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L159) in the Quick Start example. I suspect I'm getting Windows Auth problems with the HttpClient class even before we get into Identity Server specifics.

If I got past this stage I would also need to be able to handle the callback to deal with the code/access token. Is there another way to do this?

I realise that a browser window can be shown in WPF to handle everything but for complicated and political reasons within the company we would like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So the proper way to do this is use Auth Code with PKCE, you can configure this to give you a refresh token, so you can argue that you only see the browser once when initially logging in. (I advise this)

If you can't get a refresh token, you can do silent refreshes with headless browser.

If you don't want the browser window you can again have a headless browser and just interact with it via the UI, and simulate the flow without anyone seeing it. (I do not advise this)

If you don't want the browser at all, you can use Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. Please refer to [Scott Brady's blog post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) about weather you should or shouldn't use it.

> Many members of the OAuth Working Group now consider the ROPC grant type as deprecated.

And as for

> I realise that a browser window can be shown in WPF to handle everything but for complicated and political reasons within the company we would like to avoid this if possible.

Tell them it's impossible to avoid this.